# iOS : temp data is adding while calling an API

Tags: ios, objective-c, api

Here is my api while calling

```
http://jamboreebliss.com/sayar/public/api/v2/ticket/delete?
api_key=9p41T2XFZ34YRZJUNQAdm&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9yzdWIiORFdoaVIiCV8_oYP8&id[]=45,125
```

After calling at last parameter i.e **id[]** in this field, temp data is coming

```
http://jamboreebliss.com/sayar/public/api/v2/ticket/delete?
    api_key=9p41T2XFZ34YRZJUNQAdm&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9yzdWIiORFdoaVIiCV8_oYP8&id%5B%5D=45,125
```

**id%5B%5D=45,125**  this coming ( i. e **%5B%5D**)

why it is coming ? any idea ?

Comment: It's percent escaping. Also there is a space before `&id`, it should be escaped also. How is created the URL?

Comment: I added that space for understanding purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**id%5B%5D=45,125** represent `[` and `]`. The encoding is called ["URL encoding"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From apple

> Creates a copy of a string, replacing certain characters with the equivalent `percent escape sequence` based on the specified `encoding`.

Here is example code :

```
NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                        NULL,
                        (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                        NULL,
                        (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

More check this link [Percent-encoding reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

[image]

Space before `&id`

Comment: let me check this solution. Just now I understand concept of reserved characters.

Comment: how I can use this solution ? I am not getting ...plz help me

Comment: Would you post your that you are trying so far